# Why QFile("A_FIFO_NAME") call bytesAvailable always return 0

Tags: qt, qfile

I used QFile to open an Linux FIFO which will receive data each second.

```
fp = new QFile(DCB_DATA_INPUT);

if(fp->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly| QIODevice::Text))
{
    log_d(1,TAG,"Open agiin success");

    s_notifier = new QSocketNotifier(fp->handle(), QSocketNotifier::Read, this);
    s_notifier->setEnabled(true);
    connect(s_notifier, SIGNAL(activated(int)), this, SLOT(notifier_process(int)));
    return true;

}

notifier_process(int) {
qint64 avai = fp->bytesAvailable();
log_d(1,TAG,QString("%1").arg(avai));...}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is an [open bug report about this issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-15261), I'd recommend using the standard Linux API:

```
void notifier_process(int)
{
    int bytesAvailable;
    ioctl(fp->handle(), FIONREAD, &bytesAvailable);

    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    read(fp->handle(),&buffer,bytesAvailable);
    qDebug() << buffer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i almost forgot this ticket and i did use the read() instead.

Comment: @EliHuang if this answers your question, please consider marking it solved